# How long does it take for sugar to get to the hard ball stage?

Tags: sugar, candy

I tried to make nougat but just could not get to the hard ball stage.

Comment: If you don't have a thermometer you can try caramelizing the sugar in the oven.  Easier to control.

Answer (score 6):

It's not a question of "how long" as much as it's a question of "how hot." Sugar reaches the so-called hard ball stage somewhere between 250 and 265 degrees F. How long it will take your sugar to reach that temperature depends on a number of variables including the power of your cooking range and the type of vessel the sugar is being cooked in.

Use either a candy thermometer or the tried and true water testing method from which the stages get their names. When dropped into cold water, the sugar will literally form a hard ball when rolled between your fingers.

You either did not apply enough heat or you applied too much heat. The most reliable way to troubleshoot this problem is with a thermometer.

There's some great information in this article titled [How to Test Stages of Sugar](http://www.recipetips.com/kitchen-tips/t--1459/how-to-test-stages-of-sugar.asp) on RecipeTips.com

Pictured below is the example image from that article of what hard ball sugar should look like when dropped into cold water:

[image: Hard Ball stage sugar]